# Range.Locked Runtime Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue regarding setting a range of cells to be editable by a user after my code runs when the file opens. The file gets a runtime error "Unable to set the locked property of the range class".

I have done some digging online and it appears other people have the same issue when their cells are merged. My cells aren't merged.

What I am trying to do:

1. Lock all cells on all sheets apart from specific ones
2. Still allow user to group and ungroup data

The code runs fine without selecting specific cells

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.StatusBar = "Loading Please Wait..." 'change status bar text
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'freeze screen
Application.Cursor = xlWait 'change cursor

UserForm1.Show vbModeless 'show loading form
UserForm1.Repaint 'update form

    For Each ws In Sheets 'loop for every sheet

        With ws

            .Unprotect Password:="11Oceans" 'unprotect sheet
            .Range("D6:J6").Locked = False 'format certain cells to unprotect -ERROR HERE
            .Protect Password:="11Oceans", UserInterfaceOnly:=True 'protect sheet but leave data grouping
            .EnableOutlining = True

        End With

    Next ws 'next worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'return control to user
Application.StatusBar = "" 'return status bar to default
Application.Cursor = xlDefault 'return cursor to default
Unload UserForm1 'close loading form

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the _Workbook_ also locked perhaps to prevent changes?

Comment: @Macro Man Yeah it is. Should I unlock this before my ws Unprotect?

Comment: Can't do any harm to try :)

Comment: @macroMan The unprotected Workbook still gets the same error :(

Comment: Do you have any code in your `UserForm1_Activate` or `_Initialize` events? Also can you change `In Sheets` to `In Me.Sheets` so we can be certain which workbook sheets you're working with.

Comment: @Ambie I don't have any code in `_Activate` or `_Initialise`. I have changed it to `In Me.Sheets`, thank you. Could this be something really obvious that I am missing?

Comment: I have tried changing `.Range("D6:J6").Locked = False` to even just `.Range("J18").Locked = False`, a random cell that isn't used for anything

Comment: @Niall, not necessarily obvious but should be trivial. Unfortunately SO isn't a great medium to solve your problem because we'd need to have the workbook and environment it's being used in. You need to work through every cause for the `.Locked` property failing and eliminate them one by one: examples I can think of are shared workbooks, merged cells, protected books and sheets but there are no doubt others.

Comment: @Ambie Would nesting it in an if statement help? i.e. "If cell is unlocked, do nothing, otherwise use .Locked"? This would stop it from trying to unlock unlocked cells, which I guess could throw an error?

Comment: @Niall, it could do. There'll be some workbook feature that's causing this issue so you'll just need to try everything you can think of as a means of eliminating all the possibilities. An expert could solve this in 10 seconds if they could just sit at your work station so maybe see if your IT department or a knowledgeable friend/colleague could help you.